# accessing a double structure pointer, segmentation fault occured

Tags: c

```
typedef struct
{
        int member;
} mystruct;

void myfunc(mystruct **data)
{
        mystruct *const *p;
        for(p = data; *p !=NULL; p++)
        {
                printf("hello\n");
        }
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        myfunc(NULL);
}
```

tried with the above code am getting segmentation fault, its mainly something wrong in that for loop, how to just remove this segmentation fault in that for loop.... actually am learning this double pointer stuff, so i may be a little stupid in asking few question.... thanks in advance

Comment: `*p !=NULL` -> `p != NULL && *p != NULL`

Comment: `data` is `NULL`, `p` is equal to `data`, and then you dereference `p` in the `for` loop's condition. That's undefined behaviour -- a segfault in your case.

Comment: `data` is null - you are de-referencing this null pointer

Comment: @BeyelerStudios that wouldn't make sense either -- increment a pointer until it's `NULL` ?

Comment: @Quentin so that would make sense i mean here, data is passed NULL, p = data, what does this mean p !=NULL && *p != NULL, dint get the logic behind it....

Comment: Also i tried like reversing the condition in for loop like *p !=NULL && p != NULL, this will also lead to segFault.... as I told am having a very little understanding in this.

Comment: @Azeez The logic is to test that the pointed address is consistent before to access that specific address with `*p`.

Comment: Azeez You must switch the check to avoid segFault: p !=NULL && *p != NULL as commented by @BeyelerStudios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you dereference a nullpointer, you invoke undefined behaviour (e.g. a segmentation fault).

```
typedef struct
{
    int member;
} mystruct;

void myfunc(mystruct **data)
{
    mystruct *const *p;
    // this loop assumes data to be a valid pointer
    // to a NULL-terminated array!
    for(p = data; *p != NULL; p++)
    {
        printf("hello\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    mystruct s;
    mystruct *arr[2];
    arr[0] = &s; // arr[0] points to s
    arr[1] = NULL; // null-terminator
    s.member = 13;
    myfunc(arr);
    // myfunc(NULL); // undefined behaviour

    return 0;
}
```

you can fix this by checking `data` in myfunc:

```
void myfunc(mystruct **data)
{
    mystruct *const *p;
    // first check data
    if(data != NULL)
    {
        // loop still assumes data to be a NULL-terminated array!
        for(p = data; *p != NULL; ++p)
        {
            printf("hello\n");
        }
    }
}
...
myfunc(NULL); // well defined as the pointer will be checked
```

if you just want to iterate over a range, consider the standard approach:

```
void myfunc_range(mystruct *begin, mystruct *end)
{
    mystruct const *it;
    for(it = begin; it != end; ++it)
    {
        printf("hello %d\n", it->member);
    }
}

int main()
{
    mystruct s;
    mystruct arr[2];
    s.member = 42;
    myfunc_range(&s, &s + 1); // iterate over a single element
    arr[0].member = 13;
    arr[1].member = 37;
    myfunc_range(arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr)); // iterate over the whole array
    myfunc_range(arr + i, arr + i + k); // iterate over elements arr[i..i+k-1]
    myfunc_range(NULL, NULL); // well defined as NULL == NULL (an empty range)
    // myfunc(arr, &s); // undefined behaviour as s is not part of the array arr

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `*p` in the for loop dereferences the first pointer.
But that pointer is `NULL`, as you call your function with `myfunc(NULL);`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers, exactly now while accessing the NULL value in the condition part of the for loop is leading to the segmentation fault.